# Timeout in espresso tests, test doesn t run

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

There is an auxiliary class DialogIdlingResource, by which I try to run my tests. The tests take place, except this one. After pressing the button, everything stops.

```
AcceptanceHelper.clickOnButtonInLayout(R.id.mainSignButton, R.string.common_signin_button_text, R.id.inputLayout)
```

Code snippet with two helper methods:

```
 @Test
fun signInUserWithInvalidEmail() {
    goToSignIn()
    AcceptanceHelper.updateValidationTextView(R.string.ui_data_attribute_email, "kokojambo@mail.ru")
    AcceptanceHelper.updateValidationTextView(R.string.ui_data_attribute_password, VALID_PASSWORD)
    AcceptanceHelper.clickOnButtonInLayout(R.id.mainSignButton, R.string.common_signin_button_text, R.id.inputLayout)
    val idlingResource = DialogIdlingResource()
    registerDialogIdlingResource()
    unregisterDialogIdlingResource()
}
    private fun registerDialogIdlingResource() {
    val instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
    idlingResource = DialogIdlingResource()
    Espresso.registerIdlingResources(idlingResource)
}


private fun unregisterDialogIdlingResource() {
    Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(idlingResource)
}
```

Probable that the error due to the two methods of regester and unregister (idlingResource)

But in fact it should work, but may be somewhere that probably made a mistake, an auxiliary class code:

```
class DialogIdlingResource(private val waitTimeSeconds: Int = 5) : 

IdlingResource {
private var resourceCallback: IdlingResource.ResourceCallback? = null
private var startTime = -1L

override fun getName(): String {
    return DialogIdlingResource::class.java.name
}

override fun isIdleNow(): Boolean {
    if (startTime < 0) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    }
    val timeOut = System.currentTimeMillis() - waitTimeSeconds * 1000 > startTime
    if (timeOut)
        throw TimeoutException("error")
    val idle = !isDialogRunning
    if (idle && resourceCallback != null) {
        resourceCallback!!.onTransitionToIdle()
    }
    return idle
}

override fun registerIdleTransitionCallback(resourceCallback: IdlingResource.ResourceCallback) {
    this.resourceCallback = resourceCallback
}

private val isDialogRunning: Boolean
    get() {
        try {
            onView(Matchers.allOf(withId(R.id.titleTextView), ViewMatchers.withText("Warning")))
                    .check(ViewAssertions.matches(isDisplayed()))
        } catch (e: NoMatchingViewException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            System.out.println("some text")
        }
        return true
    }
```

**ALSO** try to resolve problem with next [**solution**](http://matgom.com/tutorial/2016/02/21/IdlingResource.html). And when i run just one of my test, all works is good. But if i start all my tests, i catch error. Beacause test hasn t time to check for example text in my dialog, he opened dialog and that is all.

IdlingResource class:

```
class ElapsedTimeIdlingResource(private val activity: SignActivity?) : IdlingResource {
private var callback: IdlingResource.ResourceCallback? = null

override fun getName(): String {
    return "SignInScreenTest"
}

override fun isIdleNow(): Boolean {
    val idle = isIdle
    if (idle) callback!!.onTransitionToIdle()
    return idle
}

val isIdle: Boolean
    get() = activity != null && callback != null

override fun registerIdleTransitionCallback(resourceCallback: IdlingResource.ResourceCallback) {
    this.callback = resourceCallback
}
```

}

in my test

```
val activity = mActivityTestRule.getActivity()
    val idlingResource = ElapsedTimeIdlingResource(activity)
    Espresso.registerIdlingResources(idlingResource)
    AcceptanceHelper.checkTextView(R.id.titleTextView, "Warning")
```

And i repeat, just when i start all my tests, i need to put sleep between registerIdlingResources and checktextView
somethinng like this:

```
SystemClock.sleep(5000)
```

Please help to resolve this problem. And sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but your IdlingResource looks like super complicated wait functionality.

This code snippet works for me - [github link](https://gist.github.com/vaughandroid/e2fda716c7cf6853fa79). You just have to provide needed parameters to ViewVisibilityIdlingResource constructor. One of them is `int viewId` and another `int visibility`. For example if you provide any `viewId` from inside the dialog layout and visibility `View.GONE` then this resource will block Espresso tests until view is visible or until dialog is displayed to the user.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getId()' on a null object reference` when i resolve something like this `        val idlingResource = ViewVisibilityIdlingResource(mActivityTestRule.activity.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView), 2000)`

Comment: View you are looking for belongs probably to different activity then `mActivityTestRule.activity`. You should get latest activity displayed on the screen. See this link - http://qathread.blogspot.ch/2014/09/discovering-espresso-for-android-how-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Did not catch the syntax for kotlin though.

isIdle() is always executed on main thread which should be non blocking. So rather than calling isDialogRunning() in isIdle(), 
call it in a separate thread and update the state of idlingResource(if view matched or timed out) which can then be checked by isIdle().

Hope it helps :)